# RIP always add same network adress

Tags: network, rip

From network 10.10.0.0/23 i made 10 subnetworks. But when i try to add any network address to RIP it always add 10.0.0.0.

Router configuration:

```
Router(config-router)#router rip
Router(config-router)#version 2
Router(config-router)#network 10.10.1.0
Router(config-router)#network 10.10.1.216
Router(config-router)#network 10.10.1.208
Router(config-router)#no auto-summary
Router(config-router)#exit
```

Ip routing table after configuration:

```
Router#show ip route
Codes: C - connected, S - static, I - IGRP, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2, E - EGP
       i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area
       * - candidate default, U - per-user static route, o - ODR
       P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is not set

     10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 3 subnets, 2 masks
C       10.10.1.0/25 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
C       10.10.1.208/30 is directly connected, Serial2/0
C       10.10.1.216/30 is directly connected, FastEthernet1/0
```

Topology:
[image: Topology:]

Comment: Please include the full router configuration .  Use the preformatted text option.  Please do not post the configuration as an image.

Comment: Ready, i have edited the post substituting images for text

Comment: That is not actually in the routing table as a route. Notice that there is no code next to it. The others have a code "C" showing directly connected. Neither do you have any routes added by RIP in the routing table. The only routes you have in there are the directly connected routes that would be there even if you had not configured RIP.

Comment: ¿And why does this happen? I thought maybe is for using Fast Ethernet interfaces but doesnt have any sense

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RIP always adds the classful major network to the routing table. So if you were to:

```
Router(config-router)#network 192.168.25.64
```

It would end up in the routing table like:

```
192.168.25.0/24 is variably subnetted, x subnets, x masks
```

So, working as intended. Just remember you only need to put that classful major network in the RIP configuration. And make sure to get `no auto-summary` in there so it registers the subnets.